# Installing drivers for my Radeon card 16.04

Tags: drivers, radeon

I would like to install the driver for my Radeon graphics card on Ubuntu 16.04. Is it available? If it is, how do I install it?

I tried `lspci -nn | grep` and got the following:

```
VGA 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel
Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics
 Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller
[0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD
 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M] [1002:6741] (rev ff)
```

Comment: There is no need to install any driver.

Comment: @Pilot6 why so ?

Comment: @Zacharee1 , am I to understand there is no solution at all ?

Comment: Not really on 16.04. 14.04 will be fine.

Comment: @user227495 What "solution" are you asking for? Solution of what problem? The open source driver is installed by default. And you did not mention any problems with it.

Comment: @Pilot6 , please check the link below ( in answer ). I guess " SUMO/SUMO2 " is my card and it has some drivers for 16.04. But I do not know how to install it. Also, I cannot see anything about my graphics card in " About this computer ".

Comment: Is that the only problem that you do not see information about your card? Install `mesa-utils` and you will see it.

Comment: @Pilot6 , I did try that command. But still no indication of any graphics card present.

Comment: @Pilot6, I retried the command and it said " mesa-utils is already the newest version (8.3.0-1). "

Comment: So what is the real problem? I see that you have hybrid Intel+AMD graphics. I do not see any problem that can be solved.

Comment: @Pilot6 , are you trying to say that the graphics card driver is already installed ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to say. Ubuntu is not Windows. Installing 3rd party drivers is an exception, not a rule.

Comment: @Pilot6 , I see. The reason why I asked this question is that my PC kind of hangs when the memory reaches 4GB. I thought that can be solved if graphics card comes to play.

Comment: If you have some real problem, it makes sense to describe it in a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44798/discussion-between-user227495-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

This already exists.

Comment: @yolo7398 , I tried "  sudo apt-get install mesa-utils " command. But under " About this computer ", there is no graphics card. Thanks.